# jQuery .unload() does not work, but .load() does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load and unload content dynamically using jquery.

.load() works perfectly but for some reason I can't do the same thing with .unload(). I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is my code

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
        e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link

        $( '.content-wrap' ).load('projects/project1.html');
    });

    $('#back').click(function(){
        $( '.content-wrap' ).unload('projects/project1.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot use unload() event like this. Check https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: `.unload` is not the “reverse” operation to `.load`, it does something completely different.

Comment: ahh I see. I thought it was the opposite of .load(). Thanks for clarifying this to me. So what would be the "opposite" to .load()? let's say I want to "unload" projects/project1.html

Comment: Never mind. Runthis answered the question for me :) Thanks again guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unload function in jquery is not used for this purpose. It is used to set a window unload event to happen, such as when exiting a page.

https://api.jquery.com/unload/

> The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event. Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even a page reload will first create an unload event.

If you just need to clear the element, setting the innerHTML to nothing would be sufficient.

```
$( '.content-wrap' ).html('');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dm7hhnjc/

With respect to the OP, this scope of load and unload in jquery could lead anyone astray by accident as the naming scheme is inherently confusing unless you are familiar with window.onunload already

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying this for me. I thought that .unload() was the opposite of .load(). It makes sense now. Thank you very much